# Can basin-hopping be applied for global constrained optimization?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Can we implement Basin-Hopping approach for constrained optimization problems ? The literature suggests it for unconstrained global optimization, but I have a few constraints. Can it be adapted for constraints handling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basin-hopping was initially designed for unconstrained global optimisation problems. You can extend it to constrained optimisation problems if you can take care of unfeasibilities.

Look for instance to http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2008/11/2150.pdf.

Comment: From a quick look into the work, it seems that it is tailored for box constrained optimization. Extending it to general constraints especially nonconvex ones can be a bit daunting and challenging task.

Comment: Yes, not trivial at all. But it depends on the kind of constraints....give it a thought.

Comment: It uses a local minimizer at each step, so if you use a constrained minimizer it can stay within the constraints.  It may or may not want to reject steps that go out of bounds, too.  (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/7819)  No guarantee it will find the global minimum, though.